# ASP.Net WebApi STA Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, apartment-state

This [post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/18/Creating-STA-COM-compatible-ASPNET-Applications) scratches off WebApi from being able to run in STA mode. But this post is also 2 years old.

I've been digging into the newer WebApi2 but can't seem to find a way to make [`MessageHandlers`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers) run in STA mode.

So has anyone found a way of running WebApi or WebApi2 in STA mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it seems that if you want to switch the entire request processing thread to STA mode, you're better off with [MVC](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Sep/18/Creating-STA-COM-compatible-ASPNET-Applications). However, if your handler does a one off task that doesn't involve switching the entire thread into STA mode, Web API makes it pretty easy. Here's how I did it:

```
public class StaHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // consider moving it to singleton instance to improve performance
        var staTaskScheduler = new StaTaskScheduler(100);

        return Task.Factory.StartNew<HttpResponseMessage>(() =>
        {
            //somethign that does its magic and returns a HttpResponseMessag
            return new HttpResponseMessage();
        }, cancellationToken,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            staTaskScheduler);
    }
}
```

Things to consider:

- Creating `StaTaskScheduler` is heavy. Consider moving it to a singleton or ensure it is initialized only once during App_Start
- Thread Pool Size (100 in my example) can also play a role in how well this scales. Unfortunately, there is no magic formula to get this right. I created [Web Performance Load Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293540%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to figure out a sweet spot on my servers.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers